# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64') in react native signature canvas react native fs

Tags: react-native, canvas, digital-signature, signature

I am new to react native. I have react native signature canvas code. its working but when I draw signature then I am getting error like this = undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64'). please help. whats wrong with my code.

here is code

```
export default class Kyc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       singleFileSIGN:''
    };
   this.ref = React.createRef();
  }




   handleSignature = signature => {
    const path = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + 'sign.png';
FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(path, signature.replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''), {encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64}).then(res => {
  
      // console.log(res);
      // FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path, {size: true, md5: true}).then(file => {
        FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path).then(file => {
        console.log(file);
        this.setState({ singleFileSIGN: file.uri});
        console.log(singleFileSIGN)
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("err", err);
    })
};

handleEmpty = ()=>  {
  console.log('Empty');
};

handleClear= ()=>  {
  console.log('clear success!');
};

handleEnd= ()=> {
  this.ref.current.readSignature();
};


  render () {

    return  (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      
            <View style={{flex: 1, width:355, 
                          ...Platform.select({
                  android: {
                    marginBottom:-80,
                    borderColor: '#FF8C00',
                    borderWidth:1
                  //  marginBottom:-150
                  },
                }),
                }}>
                    <SignatureScreen style={{height: '400%'}}
                        ref={this.ref}
                        onEnd={this.handleEnd}
                        onOK={this.handleSignature}
                        onEmpty={this.handleEmpty}
                        onClear={this.handleClear}
                        descriptionText={'Sign here!'}
                    />
              </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

please ignore this. I am new to react native. I have react native signature canvas code. its working but when I draw signature then I am getting error like this = undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64'). please help. whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Where are you importing FileSystem from ?

Comment: import * as FileSystem from 'react-native-fs'; please help

Comment: The code you are using is from expo import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'; is this an expo app ?

Comment: this code was available in expo but now i want to implement in react native. please help

Comment: no its not expo I am creating app using react native

Comment: Ok, you should modify the question a bit and ask to convert the expo code with fs code :) the error is coming up because EncodingType is not available in fs, you will have to find functions from the documentation of fs which matches the ones you need

Comment: whic encodingType

Comment: So you are importing from FileSystem which doenst have a properly called EncodingType so FileSystem.EncodingType is undefined thats the error

Comment: kk I lwill ook on that